# Two-dimensional view of high dimensional ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, statistics, ellipsoids

I have a $k$-dimensional ellipsoid defined as

$\left(x-\mu\right) C \left(x-\mu\right)'<1$.

As an example assume $k=3$ (in practice my $k>100$) and

$ C = \begin{pmatrix}
c_{1,1} & c_{1,2} & c_{1,3} \\
c_{2,1} & c_{2,2}  & c_{2,3} \\
c_{3,1} & c_{3,2} & c_{3,3}  \\
\end{pmatrix}$

I want to plot a two-dimensional view of it, say the first two of the $k$ dimensions. How does the $C'$ of the reduced ellipsoid look that I need to plot? I guess its not just

$ C' = \begin{pmatrix}
c_{1,1} & c_{1,2} \\
c_{2,1} & c_{2,2} \\
\end{pmatrix}$

at least the resulting ellipse looks very big compared to points I draw uniformly from within the high-dimensionsinal ellipsoid (and then look at the plot of the points' first two dimensions).

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: $C'$ would be a slice of $C$. In infer from your claims that you want to draw a projection of $C$.

Comment: See my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853351/do-ellipsoids-cast-ellipsoidal-shadows

Comment: Thanks for the hint I do look for a projection @Arnaud, I did not realise that at first. I tried to follow the solution (answer) here: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2431159/how-to-obtain-the-equation-of-the-projection-shadow-of-an-ellipsoid-into-2d-plan).
However, plotting $\mathbf{(x_{1-2}-\mu_{1-2})} \left( J - L'K^{-1}L\right)\mathbf{(x_{1-2}-\mu_{1-2})}= 1$ gave me a hugh ellipse, but maybe I missundertand something and the formula does not give the desired projection.

Comment: Dunno, but the projections of a 100 dimensional random ellipsoid are much bigger than their sections, so it seems ok.